# Make calculations across multiple tables based on the table suffix in Bigquery

Tags: sql, arrays, loops, google-bigquery

I have a database of daily tables (with prefixes formatted as yyyymmdd) with customers info, and I need to get a 90 day timeline of 90 day ARPUs (average revenue per user). i.e. one point on the graph = revenue / number of users for the previous 90 days.

I have tried the following:

```
    SELECT
    ninetyd_rev/ninetyd_userid as arpu
    From(
    SELECT
    SUM(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY activity_date ROWS BETWEEN 89 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS ninetyd_rev,
    COUNT(userid) OVER (ORDER BY activity_date ROWS BETWEEN 89 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS ninetyd_userid,
    FROM
      `table_*`
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -180 DAY))
      AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",CURRENT_DATE()))
```

(where activity_date corresponds to the table suffix)

but that results in the following error: *Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 132% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%*

I was also thinking that there might be a way to generate and array of numbers that can be looped in the interval somehow. Something like:

```
  generate array 0 to 89 as **variable x**
SELECT
    SUM(revenue)/COUNT(userid) AS arpu
    FROM
      `table_*`
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL **-x** DAY))
      AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",CURRENT_DATE())
```

Yet I have not been able to achieve anything useful and not sure if that approach is possible at all.
Thank you for all the tips!

Edit. The expected output would be

| day | arpu |
| --- | --- |
| d1 | arpu1 (d1 and previous 89 days rev/#users) |
| d2 | arpu2 (d2 and previous 89 days rev/#users) |
| dn | arpun (dn and previous 89 days rev/#users) |

ideally the days (d1, d2, ...dn) would be in yyyymmdd format.`code`

UPD. Based on the suggestion from @dikesh, I ran the query below. Yet Bigquery never finishes the calculation and does not give an output

```
WITH 
daily_userids AS (
SELECT activity_date as activity_date, userid as users 
FROM `table_x`
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",CURRENT_DATE()) 
GROUP BY 1,2),
        
daily_revenue AS (
SELECT activity_date, SUM(revenue) AS revenue 
FROM `table_x`
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",CURRENT_DATE()) 
GROUP BY 1 ),
        
-- Find number of users in last 30 days from the date
table_users AS (
SELECT t1.activity_date, count (DISTINCT t2.users) AS users
FROM daily_userids AS t1 JOIN daily_userids AS t2
ON t1.activity_date BETWEEN t2.activity_date AND DATE_ADD(t2.activity_date, INTERVAL 29 DAY)
GROUP BY t1.activity_date),
    
-- Find total revenue in last 30 days from the date
table_revenue AS (
SELECT activity_date, SUM(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY activity_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 29 FOLLOWING) AS revenue
FROM daily_revenue
)

-- FIND ARPU
SELECT activity_date, users, revenue, ROUND(revenue / users, 4) AS arpu
FROM table_users JOIN table_revenue USING (activity_date)
ORDER BY activity_date DESC
```

Comment: What is the expected output table?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you didn’t store each day’s data in a separate table - that’s not a very good design and definitely not standard practice. However, I’d start by writing an SP that dynamically generates a view over all your tables, then you can just query the view

Comment: Not my decision regarding the database design :) 
I added the expected output above. Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to you share how big your table is and from when _TABLE_SUFFIX starts ?  The analytic functions didn't partition the table and it seems to cause 'Resource Exceeded' error.

Comment: One table is approx 490 MB. As I need 90 days of  90 day arpus, thats 180 tables, i.e. today - 180 days. And this query is meant to be rerun in the future so not just a one time output

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample query to find ARPU of last two days from each date

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-09' AS day, 100 AS revenue, 'A' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-09' AS day, 110 AS revenue, 'B' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-09' AS day, 80 AS revenue, 'C' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-08' AS day, 100 AS revenue, 'B' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-08' AS day, 110 AS revenue, 'C' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-08' AS day, 80 AS revenue, 'D' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-07' AS day, 100 AS revenue, 'C' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-07' AS day, 110 AS revenue, 'D' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-07' AS day, 80 AS revenue, 'E' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-06' AS day, 100 AS revenue, 'E' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-06' AS day, 110 AS revenue, 'C' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-06' AS day, 80 AS revenue, 'A' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-05' AS day, 100 AS revenue, 'B' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-05' AS day, 110 AS revenue, 'D' AS userid),
    STRUCT(DATE '2022-05-05' AS day, 80 AS revenue, 'C' AS userid)
  ])
),
daily_userids AS (SELECT DISTINCT day, userid from table1),
daily_revenue AS (SELECT day, SUM(revenue) AS revenue FROM table1 GROUP BY day),

-- Find number of users in last 2 days from the date
table_users AS (
  SELECT t1.day, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.userid) AS users
  FROM daily_userids AS t1 JOIN daily_userids AS t2
  ON t1.day BETWEEN t2.day AND DATE_ADD(t2.day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  GROUP BY t1.day
),
-- Find total revenue in last 2 days from the date
table_revenue AS (
  SELECT day, SUM(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY day DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS revenue
  FROM daily_revenue
)
-- FIND ARPU
SELECT day, users, revenue, ROUND(revenue / users, 2) AS arpu
FROM table_users JOIN table_revenue USING (day)
ORDER BY day DESC
```

Output:

| day | users | revenue | arpu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-09 | 4 | 580 | 145.0 |
| 2022-05-08 | 4 | 580 | 145.0 |
| 2022-05-07 | 4 | 580 | 145.0 |
| 2022-05-06 | 5 | 580 | 116.0 |
| 2022-05-05 | 3 | 290 | 96.67 |

Comment: I tried a similar query, yet it gives ARPUs per day for the last 90 days. Yet what I am looking for is a 90 day timeline of 90 day ARPUs. Ie. 
Day 1 - Arpu for the past 90 days from day 1,
Day 2 - Arpu for the past 90 days from day 2,..
Day 90 - Arpu for the past 90 days from day 90

Comment: @Nata checkout the sample query I have updated

Comment: Thank you so much for this idea, @dikesh! I tried adopting it to using the table I have, i.e. replacing the 'table1' in the WITH statement in your query but my query keeps running never producing an output :/

Comment: I think the `join` to find the number of users needs to be optimized. Can you tell at which stage the query is stuck at?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how to check that. The query gets to 8/9 stages and stays at that point.

Comment: May be you should break this query into multiple queries, save the result of each into temp tables and run the subsequent query on temporary tables.

Comment: That could be a temporary solution, but I need to use the query in a visualization tool and update it at least a couple times a week, so ultimately getting to one query would be needed